# Problems finding out Active users due to Hire/Resign Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

In my `Employee` table in SQL Server I have two datetime columns: `HiringDate` and `ResignDate`. I want to create a new column `Status` (Active, Inactive) in a view.

- If HiringDate is NULL or greater than today = Inactive
- If HiringDate is Active but ResignDate is earlier than today then Status also have to be Inactive.

Do I have to make some kind of nested case to make this work and I'm also wondering do I have to convert it to date format so the time portion are not included.

Would be very thankful for help.

Here is what ive tried so far but it doesnt work properly...

```
CASE 
            WHEN CONVERT(DATE,HiringDate) IS NOT NULL 
            OR CONVERT(DATE,HiringDate) <= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) 
            THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN CONVERT(DATE,ISNULL(ResignDate, CONVERT(DATE,'2099-12-30'))) <= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) 
                    THEN 'Active'
                    ELSE 'Inactive'
                END 
            ELSE 'Inactive' 
        END as Status
```

Comment: If your columns `HiringDate` and `ResignDate` never need the time portions - just define them as datatype `DATE` - and you won't have to worry about a time portion ever again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below combine logic in one CASE expression:

```
CASE 
    WHEN HiringDate IS NOT NULL 
        or HiringDate >= GETDATE()
        or ResignDate >= GETDATE() 
    THEN 'Active' 
    ELSE 'Inactive' 
END as Status
```

Can you please try with this below new logic-

```
CASE 
    WHEN (
        CONVERT(DATE,HiringDate) IS NOT NULL 
        OR 
        CONVERT(DATE,HiringDate) <= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()
    )
    AND
    CONVERT(DATE,ISNULL(ResignDate, CONVERT(DATE,'2099-12-30'))) 
            <= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) 
    THEN 'Active'

    ELSE 'Inactive' 
END as EmployeeStatus
```

Comment: Sorry but that didnt work. When one of your conditions is right it will always be Active. I tried something like this now but it also don't work..

Comment: CASE 
   WHEN CONVERT(DATE,HiringDate) IS NOT NULL 
   OR CONVERT(DATE,HiringDate) <= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) 
   THEN 
    CASE 
     WHEN CONVERT(DATE,ISNULL(ResignDate, CONVERT(DATE,'2099-12-30'))) <= CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) 
     THEN 'Active'
     ELSE 'Inactive'
    END 
   ELSE 'Inactive' 
  END as EmployeeStatus

Comment: Hi @user2210516, I have added a new login in my answer. Can you please check this works or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below CASE logic.

```sql
CASE WHEN HiringDate IS NULL THEN 'InActive'
     WHEN CAST(HiringDate AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN 'InActive'
     WHEN HiringDate IS NOT NULL AND CAST(ResignDate AS DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) THEN 'InActive'
     ELSE 'Active'
     END As Status
```

Comment: Perfect, now i got the correct answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: please accept it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future. Choose the tick mark next to the answer